# How to list my commits in multi projects that are managed by google repo command

Tags: git, repo

I have multi projects that are managed by google repo command. I work in multi projects. Sometimes I want to list my commits and review their content in multi projects. How to do that? Any command? I can not enter into the project dirs manually and use the "git log" one by one because the projects are too many to remember.

Comment: Perhaps writing a script (or many) that can go into the different repos?

Comment: If someone knows there is an existing script, please help to provide. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [repo forall](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/develop/repo#forall). It executes the given shell command in each project. And you could use `-r` to filter the projects in regular expressions.

For example, to list the latest 3 commits in oneline format, in the repositories whose paths start with `packages/apps/` or `build/`, and use the pager `less`.

```
repo forall -p -r '^packages/apps/.+' -r '^build/.+' -c 'echo $REPO_PROJECT;git log --oneline -3' | less
```

Note that if you use environment variables like `REPO_PROJECT` in the shell command, use the single quotes `''` instead of the double quotes `""` to wrap the command. The latter makes the environment variables disabled.